# Error running Atom for Julia

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I have installed the Atom editor for julia programming. I installed the package "Atom" on Julia command-prompt. Therefore i installed the packages "ink", "julia-client", "language-julia" on Atom.
After i put the julia binary (with no error) in Atom i run the console. But the problem is that when I write code in the console, the latter does not evaluate the stuff i write in.
I think that Atom recognizes the link directory to Julia because it gives me no error, but I do not understand why the console (if it is apparently linked to Julia) does not run.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Last time I checked, you needed to do the [developer install](https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-julia-client/tree/master/docs) to get proper functionality out of Atom/Julia. Remember, this project is still very early stage... Having said that, I use it every day without any problems (although my update cycle is much longer now as sometimes you'll need to fix something with Atom/Julia after an update)

Comment: Have you actually loaded the Atom package in Julia? The [manual](https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-julia-client/tree/master/manual) says that you need to do `using Atom` in Julia. This will pre-comply the library. Also, when I did this I got 2 errors for 2 different packages which I had to build with the `Pkg.build()` function. Try to load the Atom package in Julia and see if you get any errors.